# stm32f401 I2C does not send byte after repeated start

Tags: stm32, i2c, stm32f4

I am programming an I2C master on a STM32F401 nucleo board. I program it without HAL, just using registers.

I am interfacing a peripheral, that has to be read like the following:

1. Start
2. Write Address with R/W 0
3. Write register address
4. Send repeated start condition
5. Write Address with R/W 1
6. Read data from peripheral

The first 3 steps work totally fine, but I can't send the address with R/W 1 after the restart condition.

[image]
Here you can see the timing diagram using a logic analyser. The restart condition is sent, but afterwards SCL and SDA are just low.

Here is my code

```
    i2c_start();
    if (i2c_sendAddr(TLC2991_ADDR)) { //returns != 0 if NACK
        fault = true;
        i2c_end();
        I2C1->SR1 &= ~I2C_SR1_AF;
        return -1;
    }
    i2c_sendByte(VOLTAGE_REG_OFFS + 2 * ch);
    i2c_wfw();
    i2c_start();
    i2c_sendByte(TLC2991_ADDR | 1); //tried i2c_sendAddr too
    u8 msb = i2c_recvByte(1);
    u8 lsb = i2c_recvByte(0);
```

And the functions called

```
void i2c_start() {
    I2C1->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_START;
    while (!I2C1->SR1 & I2C_SR1_SB);
}

int i2c_sendAddr(u8 addr) {
    I2C1->DR = addr;
    while (!(I2C1->SR1 & I2C_SR1_ADDR))
        if (I2C1->SR1 & I2C_SR1_AF)
            return -1;
    I2C1->SR2; //generates a read, clears ADDR
    return 0;
}

int i2c_sendByte(u8 data) {
    while (!(I2C1->SR1 & (I2C_SR1_TXE | I2C_SR1_AF)));
    I2C1->DR = data;
    return I2C1->SR1 & I2C_SR1_AF ? -1 : 0;
}

//wait for byte transfer
void i2c_wfw() {
    while (!(I2C1->SR1 & (I2C_SR1_BTF | I2C_SR1_AF)));
}
```

The TXE bit is high before setting the DR after the restart, afterwards it is low, but the I2C does not transmit anything. Please point out what I missed.

I have also checked the SDA line with an oscilloscope and there are no glitches or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest trying the following:

i2c_start: `while (!I2C1->SR1 & I2C_SR1_SB);` -> `while (!(I2C1->SR1 & I2C_SR1_SB));`

i2c_sendByte: Move `I2C1->DR = data;` to first line. Replace check for TXE with check for BTF.

don't call `i2c_wfw` after `i2c_sendByte(VOLTAGE_REG_OFFS + 2 * ch);`, it will be done in `i2c_sendByte` as above.

use `i2c_sendAddr` instead of `i2c_sendByte` after repeated start.

Also, you check for AF in i2c_sendByte and i2c_wfw() but do not handle errors properly. It is better not to check it at all than have unpredictable code flow.
I'd recommend looking at flowcharts in [AN2824](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/5d/ae/a3/6f/08/69/4e/9b/CD00209826.pdf/files/CD00209826.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00209826.pdf) and quite nice [code example](https://github.com/LonelyWolf/stm32/blob/master/bike-computer/i2c.c) at GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the check for SB really was the issue, I didn't even see that i missed the () there.